# c++ class member operator definition with no return value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value

I tried to refresh my c++ knowledge and found a strange behaviour. When I declared a class and overloaded an operator in it, I forgot that the operator has a return value. This caused some behaviour I cannot explain.
Here is the code:

```
class myClass{
    double i;
    myClass(double value): i(value){}
    myClass operator+ (const double &param)
    {
        i = i + param;
    }
};
```

So, the operator+ should return a value with type myClass, but instead it just adds param to member i.
When I tried this operator in my program by

```
myClass A(10.5);
A+10.0;
```

the result is A.i = 20.5, as i would expect. But if I change the code to

```
A = A + 10.0;
```

The result is A.i = nan, or some very small number. I realized, that the operator+ should return a value by definition, but I didn't add return to its definition.
My question is, what is returned in this case? Some random garbage value from memory? Why does the compiler not enforce to add a return to the operator definition if it is expected to return a value with myClass type?

Comment: In short: what you wrote has undefined behavior, the compiler is not required to catch it, and anything at all can happen at runtime.

Comment: `A+10.0;` should not change members of A, that is what `operator +=` is for! This is just super confusing

Comment: Yes, it is confusing. First I tried A = A + 10.0, and when I realized that is not working as I expected, then I tried plain A+10.0. I would not use this way my operator, just tried if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some random garbage value from memory?

Most likely. Formally, as already noted, the behaviour is undefined, so anything is allowed, but most implementations will return some garbage value.

> Why does the compiler not enforce to add a return to the operator definition if it is expected to return a value with myClass type?

Because a function that has a return type doesn't need to return at all. There can be good reasons for having functions with a return type that always throw an exception, for example, in which case a diagnostic for a missing `return` statement is only a hindrance. That could even happen in ways the compiler cannot possibly see, for example when the last statement of the function is a call to another function that doesn't return normally.

Sort of an example:

```
int negate(int i) {
  if (i >= -INT_MAX)
    return i;

  /* i cannot be negated */
  abort();
}
```

You might write functions like this to prevent silently going on when `INT_MIN` is passed, to make debugging easier. In this case, the fact that there is no `return` statement after `abort();` is not a problem. Admittedly, this function does have a `return` statement, but as far as the compiler knows, it's possible for this function to return by reaching the closing `}`.

Some compilers do have an option for warning about a missing `return` statement, so you could try to turn up your warning level.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behaviour. So it can return anything that is present in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Just a garbage value, you are telling to expect a return value but not actually telling it to return anything.